# What is the safe way to run apache

Tags: apache2, webserver

I installed apache according to the description given [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/install.html). I want to know what is the safe way to run Apache that means , it is impossible to run Apache without using sudo, I want to know whether this is safe or is there a accepted way of running Apache.

Comment: I doubt why you need `sudo` to run apache, so far, I've always installed apache from Ubuntu repositories (i.e. using Synaptic or Software Center) and it never required any root privileges to run.

Comment: if that is a concern why would you use the source to install apache and not the pre-configured and hardend LAMP stack Ubuntu has in the repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not certain about security considerations when running Apache, you probably don't want to install Apache from source. I'd recommend installing Apache with `sudo apt-get install apache2` or through the Software Center.

Installing Apache with aptitude will automatically register Apache as a system service, which solves the problem of running Apache in a reasonably secure way, as long as your system configuration isn't highly customized.